# Having trouble with interfaces and foreach loops

Tags: java, foreach, interface

Can you use a for each loop to display an interface and if so how? In addition, how do you display only objects of one type from an array list ?

For example, if you have a cat and dog classes that implement the same interface, I want to display all the elements of an ArrayList of that interface type, using a for each loop.

Suppose the interface is named animal, and animals is the variable  of the ArrayList.  So would it be `for (animal animals: b) System.out.println (b);`

And how would you only display the cat objects and not the dog objects?

Comment: Please explain better what you are looking for. It would also help to add a tag of the relevant language (Java,C#,etc...). If you can supply a code sample, it would be great.

Comment: I'm using java and what I'm confused about is if you have a cat and dog class in a interface and you what to display the interface using. For each loop would be like animal is the interface and animals is the name of the Arraylist so would it be for (animal animals: b) System.out.println (b); and also how would you only display the cat objects and not the dog object

Comment: I added your comment to the question. It shouldn't be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, assuming you have an `Animal` interface, and classes `Dog` and `Cat` that implement it, this is how you'll iterate over the list :

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
...

foreach (Animal animal : animals) {
    System.out.println(animal);
}
```

And if you want to only display the Cats :

```
foreach (Animal animal : animals) {
    if (animal instanceof Cat) 
        System.out.println(animal);
}
```